# How can I figure out which process is opening the certain tcp port?

Tags: linux, ssh, netstat, fuser

I usually use *fuser* command to check pid opening the certain tcp port like the following

```
fuser 22/tcp //To get pid opening the 22 tcp port
```

I've got a reference board which running a embedded linux.
It have been already opening 22 tcp port for ssh connection.
But fuser doesn't display output anything about 22 port.
So I tried another ssh daemon to open 322 port then tried to check pid using fuser, it worked fine.

```
root@imx6qsabreauto:~# netstat -nlt | grep 22
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4224            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:322             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::322                  :::*                    LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN

root@imx6qsabreauto:~# fuser 322/tcp
351

root@imx6qsabreauto:~# ps -ef | grep 351
root       351     1  0 01:46 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/dropbear -r /etc/dropbear/dropbear_rsa_host_key -p 322 -B

root       379   315  0 02:11 ttymxc3  00:00:00 grep 351


root@imx6qsabreauto:~# fuser 22/tcp
==> This output nothing !!
```

How can I figure out which process is opening tcp 22 port.
(In the board, lsof command is not available and.. netstat doesn't have -p option.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I you have `/proc` mounted and `bash` and `readlink` both installed,
You can write a small bash script that parses `/proc/net/tcp`, and scan `/proc/*/fd/` to find the corresponding socket.

I'm not so familiar with embedded linux, but if you cannot find `readlink`, it may be included in `busybox`.

`/proc/net/tcp` is something like

```
sl  local_address rem_address   st tx_queue rx_queue tr tm->when retrnsmt   uid  timeout inode
0: 00000000:4E7A 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 13128 1 ffff8800cf960740 99 0 0 10 0
```

The `local_address` is hex string of `HOST:PORT`, so the script searches for `:0016` when you want to search tcp 22 port.

Once it founds the row which contains `:0016` in `local_address`,
the `inode` is the corresponding socket number.

Then it searchs for `/proc/*/fd/*` which has the socket number using `readlink` command.

```
#!/bin/bash
PORT="$1"
HEX_PORT=$(printf %04X $PORT)
INODE=""
if ! [ "$PORT" ];then
  echo "usage $0 [PORT]"
  exit
fi
while read num host_port _ _ _ _ _ _ _ inode _; do
  if [[ $host_port =~ :"$HEX_PORT"$ ]];then
    INODE=$inode
  fi
done < /proc/net/tcp
if ! [ "$INODE" ];then
  echo "no process using $PORT"
  exit
fi
for fn in /proc/[1-9]*/fd/*; do
  if [ "$(readlink $fn)" = "socket:[$INODE]" ];then
    tmp=${fn%/fd*}
    echo ${tmp#/proc/}
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a version of ymonad's script that runs on a Tomato/BusyBox router:

```
#!/bin/sh

# This works with BusyBox on a Tomato router

PORT="$1"
HEX_PORT=`printf %04X $PORT`
INODE=""
if ! [ "$PORT" ]; then
    echo "Find the process that is listening on an open TCP network port."
    echo "usage $0 [PORT]"
    exit 2
fi
# sl localip:port remip:port st tx_q:rx_q tr:when retrns uid timeout inode ...
while read num host_port _ _ _ _ _ _ _ inode _; do
    port=`echo "$host_port" | awk -F: '{print $2}'`
    if [ "$port" = "$HEX_PORT" ]; then
        INODE=$inode
    fi
done < /proc/net/tcp
if ! [ "$INODE" ]; then
    echo "no process using $PORT"
    exit 1
fi
echo "found inode $INODE"
f=`ls -l /proc/[1-9]*/fd/* 2>/dev/null | fgrep "socket:[$INODE]" | awk '{print $9}'`
if ! [ "$f" ] ; then
    echo "no process found using inode $INODE"
    exit 1
fi
pid=`echo "$f" | awk -F/ '{print $3}'`
echo "Process matching PID=$pid:"
ps w | awk "\$1==$pid {print}"
```

Comment: An expectation included in the answer would be cool on which systems it's expected to run.

Comment: suggest change `fgrep` to `grep -F`

Answer (score 1):

If you have or can get `ss` on your device it can show you the PID:

```
ss -ltp # for TCP
ss -lup # for UDP
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @ymonad !! :)
As your mention, I've been able to get pid corresponding to the port like the following.

```
root@imx6qsabreauto:~# cat /proc/net/tcp
  sl  local_address rem_address   st tx_queue rx_queue tr tm->when retrnsmt   uid  timeout inode

   0: 00000000:1080 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 1018 1 d8d90a00 100 0 0 10 0

   1: 00000000:0DA2 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 842 1 d8d90000 100 0 0 10 0

   2: 00000000:006F 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 2515 1 d8dc8000 100 0 0 10 0

   3: 0100007F:0035 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 877 1 d8d90500 100 0 0 10 0

root@imx6qsabreauto:~# cat /proc/net/tcp6
  sl  local_address                         remote_address                        st tx_queue rx_queue tr tm->when retrnsmt   uid  timeo
ut inode
   0: 00000000000000000000000000000000:006F 00000000000000000000000000000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0
 0 2518 1 d8dd0000 100 0 0 10 -1
   1: 00000000000000000000000001000000:0035 00000000000000000000000000000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0
 0 881 1 d8de0000 100 0 0 10 -1
   2: 00000000000000000000000000000000:0016 00000000000000000000000000000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0
 0 4933 1 d8da0000 100 0 0 10 -1
```

Your shell script is working fine, it can get pid properly as like below.

```
root@imx6qsabreauto:~# /tmp/find.sh 22
1
```

Odd thing is the result pid is 1. 
It's init process ;;

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 04:21 ?        00:00:04 /sbin/init
```

I think I need to figure out more how init process opens 22 tcp port.
Really thank you. :D I've learned a lot. Thanks again !!